# ASP.NET MVC Can I have a controller called PropertiesController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn asp.net MVC.

I have created a model called Property, I have then created a controller called PropertiesController. However when I run my code I get a 403 error when navigating to /Properties

If I rename my controller to Properties1Controller and navigate to /Properties1 it works.

I assume there is a conflict between the name of my controller and the Properties folder (mine contains AssemblyInfo.cs).

Is there a way around this or is it best to avoid controllers called Properties?

Comment: Not completely sure, but maybe [this setting](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/) could help you out.

Comment: Personally it seems that unless your app is concerned with only a small world object set (which I doubt)... then a model called Property is a pretty ambiguous name... property of what? Regardless of a conflict I would suggest you name the model more accurately.

Comment: I am adapting an existing app which has a Property database table for storing information about properties (ie pubs, shops, houses etc) This is why the name

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC3 routing reserved words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194624/asp-net-mvc3-routing-reserved-words)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a conflict here. In your project you already have a `Properties` folder which holds the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. I'd choose a different name for your controller.

It may be possible to get working with routing but in reality it's much simpler in the long run to stay away from anything non standard.